# reading system mails in debian buster

Tags: debian, email

after today update from thunderbird

```
thunderbird --version
 Thunderbird 91.5.0
```

I missed my local unix account for system-mails like from apt-listchanges. It seems it is dropped.

I know I can read it with `mail -u myuser`  but this is not easy to handle for me. Is there a program with an tui available?

Comment: Has it disappeared from Accounts > Other account? (Not Accounts > Mail account)

Comment: would it be so hard to drop in a pop or imap server?

Comment: @symbean yes for me.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `thunderbird` has dropped support for local mails. `claws` [still supports](https://www.claws-mail.org/faq/index.php/General_Information#Can_Claws_Mail_handle_local_unix_mailboxes.3F) it.

`claws` is available in the debian repositories as `claws-mail`, once installed you may just define a new account with username `john` and email `john@mymachine`. Select the protocol as `Local mbox file` in the account settings and - using debian's standard - adapt the `Local mailbox` from `/var/mail` to `/var/spool/mail`.

Retrieve mails manually via the `Get Mail` button top left or adapt how mails are fetched in configuration->preferences. It is quite straight-forward.